# Makefile: add library to another project

Tags: c++, c, static, makefile, .a

I want to change an existing makefile to include another static library that I made myself. I followed some instructions to make the library; it currently holds all the `.o` files except for `main.o`. Let's call my library `libABC.a`. If it makes a difference, the package I'm modifying is written in C++ and the library I'm including is written in C.

So far I've added `-lABC` to my library list and placed the library in the same directory as the other libraries so that I don't have to add another `-L` command. I've moved all the header files to the `/include` directory of the package (not sure if I had to do this) so I can avoid adding another `-I` command. Compiling as it is gives me no errors, but if I try to add a `#include` command for one of the header files from the library and call a function, I get a `undefined reference to function()` error.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Are headers written in C wrapped in `extern "C" { }`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Answer (score 1):

Since the package is written in C++ and your library is written in C, you probably need to use `extern "C"` linkage, since C++ is probably expecting to name-mangle your symbols.

The easiest way is to wrap your C function definitions in the header in an `extern "C"` block, like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int myFunction();
int someOtherFunction(char *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

Make sure to only wrap your own function definitions within the block; any external libraries that you are `#include`ing from your header should be outside the block.

See also: [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)